# Delegation between 2 different ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

This is my first `ViewController`:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class FirstViewController: UIViewController, someProtocol
{
    weak var theCtrl = SecondaryViewController()
    var changer = "test"


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        theCtrl?.chng = self
    }


}
```

and this is my second one, including the protocol declaration:

```
import UIKit


protocol someProtocol : class
{
    var changer:String{get}
}

@IBDesignable
class SecondaryViewController: UIViewController
{
    weak var chng : someProtocol?


    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
        {
            didSet
            {
                print(chng?.changer)
            }

        }

    }
```

What i am trying to achieve is pass the variable declared in the `FirstViewController` to the `SecondaryViewController`. While i how to achieve this using a reference between those two `viewControllers`, know how the MVC model works and have managed to get a working delegation model between a `UIView` and a `ViewController` everything i tried on this one seems to return nil instead of the value of the variable i am declaring. Any clue why?Is there a more "elegant" way for the above code to work? Thank you in advance. I am using xCode 7.1.

edit: Here is my storyboard. The master is the red and the green is the detail.

[image: storyboard]

There is nothing more to include since this is all my code and i also included the storyboard with all the segues and the elements it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case for this to work is enough to remove the `weak` befor the `var theCtrl`.

From documentation:

> ARC automatically sets a weak reference to nil when the instance that
>   it refers to is deallocated.

After you init `SecondaryViewController` object there is no one `strong` reference to it the `theCtrl` object is deallocated and it set to `nil`. Thats why in this line of code `theCtrl?.chng = self` you have `nil`

If you want only set the `changer` value to `SecondaryViewController` it will better to set it in `init` method for example. Your scheme is very tangle the code

In this case the problem also is that you create an object `theCtrl` inside `FirstViewController`, but during the transition, the new object of `SecondViewController` is created and this object have no delegate, you set delegate to other object that create with `theCtrl = SecondaryViewController()`. You don't need to create a `SecondViewController` direct but get the link to the created object from storyboard in `prepareForSegue` method for example like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) { 
    if let identifier = segue.identifier { 
        switch identifier { 
        case "SIDSecond": 
            theCtrl = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController 
            theCtrl?.chng = self 

        default: 
            break 
        } 
    } 
}
```

But first you need to set Storyboard Segue Identifire to `SIDSecond` for example

Comment: I completely removed the `weak` before `theCtrl` but i still get a nil when i call `print(chng?.changer)` in my `SecondaryViewController`

Comment: @Korpel Can you share the link to your project to view all code?

Comment: This is all my code.. Don't get confused with `@IBDesignable `.

Comment: @Korpel or try to remove the `weak` keyword befor the `var chng`. You don't need `weak` references here becouse you have no reference cycle between class instances. Your `SecondaryViewController` creates insede the `FirstViewController` and when you remove the `FirstViewController` it automaticly clear all it objects (if there is no references to it inside other objects)

Comment: Even though i removed all `weak` reference from my code i still get nil when i try to `print(chng?.changer)`

Comment: @Korpel You say that this is all your code, but you have  `@IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!` object that have `didSet` and you have storybord with this. When `didSet` calling? It happenes with some button click or after `init` of your `SecondViewContorller` class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94521/discussion-between-alex-p-and-korpel).

Comment: @Korpel This discussion not for comments, join the chat on the link in the comments above

Answer (score 0):

didSet is called after the init of second view controller but after view did load of first viewcontroller, that's all. You can not use didSet on an iboutlet in this way.

Check chng?.changer on a later point in time, like view did load of second view controller, it will not be nil.

And remove all the "weak" declarations, you don't need them.